# If - else if - else condition in react native jsx

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am currently in the process of understanding the syntax of if - else if - else statements in React Native. Below is a simple if - else condition which I understand:

```
{variable === 0 ? (
    ...
): (
    ...
})
```

However, when adding another condition to make an if - else if - else statement, I am coming across problems.

```
{variable === 0 ? (
    ...
): {variable === 1 ? (
    ...
): (
    ...
})
```

If anyone can point out my flaw, I would much appreciate it!

Comment: Just a note - this isn't specific to react, this the syntax for ternary operators in JavaScript. If the syntax ends up getting confusing or verbose, you can absolutely use if/ else if/ else blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need another braces in the second condition and swap the brackets at the end.

This format may help you to understand it better:

```
{
  variable === 0 ?
    (...)
    :
    variable === 1 ?
      (...)
      :
      (...)
}
```

Comment: exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> {variable === 0 ? (
> ...
> ): (
> ...
> })         <<<----

Now you see the last line I have pointed. You have brackets in wrong order.
The correct order is

{variable === 0 ? (
...
): (
...
**)}**

Note the order of the brackets in last line.

Comment: Oops silly mistake, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Don't forgot to up vote the answer as this help others as well.